# Insert primary keys from two newly created tables in a relationship table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one table which contained 4 records (PersonName, CityName, CityState, CityCountry) in two different tables. One of the tables now has personID, personName and the other one has Cityid, CityName, CityState, CityCountry.

Now I created third table which hold PersonId, CityId. How can I populate that table with the ids of person and city from the original table since they are split now. I want to get the ids from the newly created tables based on the relationship they had in the original table.

Comment: Do you still have the original?

Comment: yes I still have the original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just join back to the original table?

```
INSERT PersonCity (PersonID, CityID)
SELECT  p.PersonID, c.CityID
FROM    OriginalTable o
        INNER JOIN Person p
            ON p.PersonName = o.Personname
        INNER JOIN City c
            ON c.CityName = o.CityName
            AND c.CityState = o.CityState
            AND c.CityCountry = o.CityCountry;
```